# horizontal menu using % positioning

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I am making a menu that is a div with `with:100%;` and `height:45px;`

each element inside the menu are divs. My goal is to make it adapt to any screen resolution so I start by placing the first div with a `margin-left:2%;`but the for the next one I am not sure of what I must use.

I could make the first element in `float:left;` and use margin like `margin-left:10%;` but then if we change the screen resolution it's not good anymore. If I don't put anything it goes under the first button. If I use the `margin-left` in px it won't be good because of the first `margin-left:2%;` How can I achieve this?

This is what I curently have(you can see that the buttons get under the first one):
[image]

Comment: Some interpunction would be welcome. I don't think many people will bother even reading this.

Comment: Do a search for response design and also CSS 3 @media directive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use display:inline-block; and whatever the margins that are great for you?
Meaning that, the first element can have 2% and the second one as well:

```
<div id="menu">
<div class="element">1</div>
<div class="element">2</div>
</div>
```

​

```
#menu{
    width:100%;
    height:45px;    
    background:#f00;
}
.element{
    background:#0f0;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:2%;
}
```

​

I think you should provide something like a jsfiddle source when asking these type of questions :)

Comment: seems to be working but the second div get a margin-top of aprox 20px automatically is this something known or is it just my code

Comment: maybe a browser issue? I tested it on jsfiddle with chrome :\

Comment: ok fixed it. It was just few lines that needed to be changed! thx for you answer.

Comment: you're more than welcome, and that's my first answer on stackoverflow - yay :)